# Silverlight: Scrollviewer only appears when content overflows?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, scrollviewer

I'm using Silverlight 4. I have a `UserControl` whose `LayoutRoot` is wrapped in a `ScrollViewer`. I'd like the scroll bar to only appear if the `LayoutRoot` overflows the page. It is possible to do it automatically, or should I write code to detect if the content will overflow and set the scrollbar visibility accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it automatically using the [`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility.aspx) and [`ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility.aspx) properties. Here's a list of all possible values for those properties (the [`ScrollBarVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollbarvisibility.aspx) enumeration):

- Disabled
- Auto
- Hidden
- Visible

I think "Auto" is what you're looking for:

> **Auto**: A ScrollBar appears and the dimension of the ScrollViewer is applied to the content when the viewport cannot display all of the content. For a horizontal ScrollBar, the width of the content is set to the ViewportWidth of the ScrollViewer. For a vertical ScrollBar, the height of the content is set to the ViewportHeight of the ScrollViewer.

Hope this helps!